# Assign a value to a pointer of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm using a pointer to an array in a function that reference a array in the main function.  I've completely forgotten about pointers.  I'm trying:

```
    int main(void){
   int length;
   char punct;
   string password;

   cout << "Enter length of passwords: " << endl;
   cin >> length;
   char array[length];

   //run random password generator here                                          

    password = generator(*array);

    cout << "Here is your password: " << endl;
    return 0;
    }

    char* generator(char* array){
    int counter = 0;
    int random;
   while(counter <= 8){
    random = rand() % 200 + 32;
     if(random >= 32 && random != 95 && random != 127)
     char
   }
   return result;
   }
```

I'm getting errors but can't quite put a finger on what I'm screwing up here.

```
  He are the errors (sorry for not including them in the initial post):
  password.cpp:7:14: error: two or more data types in declaration of ‘main’
  password.cpp: In function ‘char* generator(char*)’:
  password.cpp:31:3: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘}’ token
  password.cpp:32:10: error: ‘result’ was not declared in this scope
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: I simply do not know where to begin. http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources

Comment: -1 "Getting errors" is not very useful and make the question useless to others. Explain *what* the error(s), summarized in the title, are - 1. Copy and paste the errors in a question 2. Before you post, search for said error(s)

Comment: If you know that you've forgotten something, it's generally a good idea to refresh your memory before asking others and making yourself look very ignorant.

Comment: I read up on pointers again here:  http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: And I added the original code not just a summary.  Thanks for the input on looking ignorant, but I think lacking knowledge is probably the right wording here.  I post in another forum mostly and forget the etiquette in this one so please accept my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,i can tell you many reasons for the errors If you are using the exact program to compile,

1. `length` does not has an initialization
2. The `signature` of the function `otherFunction` varies between where it is called and its definition
3. `*array[i]` does not make any sense in the definition of `otherFunction` since `array[i]` itself is a dereference operation

I think this is what you are expecting

```
    char* otherFunction(char[] array)
    {
        array[0] = 'x';
        array[1] = 'y';
        return array;
    }
    int main()
    {
       int length =5;
       char array[length] = "array";
       printf("%s Before otherFunction",array);
       char* newArray = otherFunction(array);
       printf("%s After otherFunction",array);
    }
```

O/P:

```
array Before otherFunction
xyray After otherFunction
```

Comment: Ok...that was the answer I was looking for. Thank you so much.  I many times when I jump on Stack try and paraphrase my code so as not to burden people trying to help me out.  It obviously backfires at times and leads to some people who troll and make rude comments.  But I thank you sir or madam very much for your help.

Comment: @Verber the community is polite to us provided we provide them more information on the question in our mind. nyways wc.   :)

Comment: I agree and it was my bad...but there's a decent way to approach things and a jerkish way as well.  A simple "More on the errors and elaborate on your question please" would have sufficed.  I've gotten -1 or less on questions that I"ve provided all available information and source code to.  Not that I need my rep number to validate myself.  I"m just playing around in C++ tonight..not my forte.  I do appreciate the help...that one comment just rubbed me the wrong way.  I help out people where I can without the slightest jab at them...no matter how little they know.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to display confusion in regards to pointer fundamentals. There are six erroneous lines in your eight lines of code. Which book are you reading?

Comment: Yes this was from the sad depths of my memory without enough reference before posting.  I apologize.